# Initialize struct with global scope where type depends on boolean

Tags: go, struct, types, scope

I started using Golang recently and stumbled across a problem:

I have two structs, `human` and `alien`, which are both based on the `creature` struct. I want to initialize one of them based on the value of the `isAlien` boolean inside of an if-statement.

Using the `human := human{}` notation or the alien equivalent inside the if blocks to initialize, the instances aren't accessible from outside of the if-statement.

On the other hand, the usual solution of declaring the type and the name of the variable before the if-statement and initializing the variable inside the if-statement doesn't work, because there two are different types:

```
var h human //use human or alien here?
if isAlien {
  h = alien{} //Error: incompatible types
} else {
 h = human{}
}
//same when swapping human with alien at the declaration
```

I know that I could just declare both types before the if-statement but that solution doesn't seem elegant to me.

Is there some obvious solution that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, the problem is clearly represented by this statement:

```
var h human //use human or alien here?
```

If you plan to use that `h` variable there after creating the objects, then the type of `h` must be one that can accept either a `human` or `alien` as a value.

The way to do this in Go is by using an `ìnterface` that both `alien` and `human` can fulfil.

So you should declare an interface like:

```
type subject interface {
    // you should list all functions that you plan to use on "h" afterwards
    // both "human" and "alien" must implement those functions 
}
```

Then:

```
var h subject
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I think I'll just have to learn a bit more about interfaces and structs...

Comment: @phmrz Here is an example of this with some type assertions and a type switch. Admittedly, `type CreatureType` is a little redundant here, but could (and should) be used in places where you don't need the concrete type, but just need to know what it is. https://play.golang.org/p/xhKU8GYX2SX

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm going to go out on a limb and say you're probably thinking about this the wrong way.

The first question that occurs to me looking at your example is: what's the return type of this function? In other words, what signature do you *need* `h` to be? If `alien` has an embedded struct `creature` (which seems to be the inheritance pattern you're trying to follow), and you return a `human` from your function after declaring `h` to be a `creature`, anything that consumes your function will only know that it's dealing with a `creature`, so there's no point in declaring it a `human` or an `alien` in the first place.

I *suspect* that what you really want to be doing is moving away from concrete structs here and instead using interfaces. In that world, you'd have a `creature` interface, and both `human` and `alien` would satisfy the `creature` interface. You wouldn't necessarily know which one you were dealing with downstream, but you'd be able to reliably call `creature` methods and the appropriate `human` or `alien` implementation would be invoked.

Comment: @phmrz Feel free to toss me an upvote if the answer was good :D

Comment: Haha tragic. Oh well! Happy hunting.